# Mapbox GL/Maplibre GL 'to-number' fallback if null and not 0

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl, maplibre-gl

As the documentation states, in the style specification expressions, the `to-number` expression converts `null` values to `0` as intended behavior. For my use case, `null` and `0` mean different things, as `0` is a valid value.

Here is and example of how I'd hope to style my data:

```
'paint': {
      'circle-color': [
        'case',
          ['all', [">=", ["to-number", ["get", "value"]], 0], ["<", ["to-number", ["get", "value"]], 100]], '#fff',
          ['all', [">=", ["to-number", ["get", "value"]], 100], ["<", ["to-number", ["get", "value"]], 500]], '#000',
          "#2f2f2f"
      ]
    },
```

0-100 are white, 100-500 are black, and anything else (`null` included) are `#2f2f2f`.

How could I make a `case` statement catch `null` values? I've tried using the `==` operator for `null`, as well as using `to-string == ''`. Neither worked for me, or their behavior impacted the other valid values.

I'm using a `pg_tileserv` instance to serve my data if that makes a difference.

Comment: you can try to use `["coalesce", ["get", "value"], -1]` if `value` is a number then `to-number` is not needed anymore. [coalesce docs](https://maplibre.org/maplibre-gl-js-docs/style-spec/expressions/#coalesce)

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested this, but this make non-number values red:

```
["case", ["typeof", ["get", "value"]], "number", [ /* insert handling of number here */ ], "red"]
```

If your non-null values are string not number, change to `"string"`.